# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{1 + x\cos(x)}{x(1-x^2e^{2\sin(x)})}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, exponential-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral: $$\int \frac{1 + x\cos(x)}{x(1-x^2e^{2\sin(x)})}\, dx$$
I have no idea how to approach this problem at all. Could someone please guide me through the steps to solve this integral? Are there any specific trigonometric identities or techniques that I should apply? Any insights or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given,

$$I=\int \frac{1 + x\cos(x)}{x(1-x^2e^{2\sin(x)})}\, dx$$

Substitue $xe^{sinx}=t$

$$I=(-1)\int \frac{1}{t^3-t} \,dt$$

For generalizing;

> $$I=\int \frac{1}{t(t^n-1)} \,dt=\frac{ln(t^n-1)}{n}-ln(t)+c$$
>
> $$Or$$
>
> $$I=\frac{ln\left(1-\frac{1}{t^n}\right)}{n}+c$$

Put $n=2$ in the above generalized integral;

$$I=(-1)\frac{ln\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{2}+c$$

I think you can take it from here.

> Extras -
>
> $xe^{sinx}=t$
>
> $e^{sinx}(1+xcosx)dx=dt$
>
> $\frac{e^{sinx}(1+xcosx)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{x}dt$
>
> $\frac{(1+xcosx)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{t}dt$

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful

Comment: I wonder if you did not miss a minus sign. Take tou last result, replace $t$ by its definition and differentiat wrt $x$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you so much, will change it right away, i hope the rest of the answer is right.

Comment: Everything is fina and nice and (+1)